# Finding alphanumeric using ruby

Tags: ruby, assertion

New to this forum.
Trying to run a test to find  `â` or `€`
Using assertion

```
text.include? "â" , "€"
```

But getting errors.

Comment: *"getting errors"* is a bit vague

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
text.include?("â") || text.include?("€")
```

OR:

```
/â|€/.match(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, since the `include?` method does not take an array:

```
['â', '€'].any? { |char| text.include?(char) }
```

Comment: A rare opportunity to use this shortcut `['â', '€'].any? &text.method(:include?)`

Comment: Not working. Is there anyway I can ignore all alphanumeric characters using text. command,

Comment: Perhaps it is the right time to ask you, @ranjanAgarwal, what kind of errors you get? And, since not all versions of Ruby play well with UTF8, what version of Ruby you use?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using minitest? You can use [`assert_match`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_match):

```
assert_match(/[â€]/, "text with â")
#=> true

assert_match(/[â€]/, "text with €")
#=> true

assert_match(/[â€]/, "text without")
#=> MiniTest::Assertion: Expected /[â€]/ to match "text without".
```